# How can I update a separate variable inside a for-loop in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to print the values in my 2D array with margins from A - J. My problem is that the margin does not increment from A.

I have tried moving the  `++k` around in the loop but the margin only repeats "A".

```
const int SIZE = 10;
int array_2D[SIZE][SIZE];   // declaring here for context; array was created in
                            // a separted function

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    int k = 65;
    cout << char(k) << " | ";
    ++k;

    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << array_2D[i][j] << "   ";     
    }
    cout << endl;    
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
A | 00   08   15   01   10   05   19   19   03   05   
B | 06   00   02   08   02   12   16   03   08   17   
C | 12   05   00   14   13   03   02   17   19   16   
D | 08   07   12   00   10   13   08   20   16   15   
E | 04   12   03   14   00   05   02   12   14   09   
F | 08   05   03   18   18   00   04   02   10   19   
G | 17   16   11   03   09   07   00   03   05   09   
H | 07   06   11   10   11   11   07   00   14   09   
I | 10   04   05   15   17   01   07   17   00   09   
J | 05   20   07   04   18   19   19   03   10   00
```

But I'm getting this:

```
A | 00   08   15   01   10   05   19   19   03   05   
A | 06   00   02   08   02   12   16   03   08   17   
A | 12   05   00   14   13   03   02   17   19   16   
A | 08   07   12   00   10   13   08   20   16   15   
A | 04   12   03   14   00   05   02   12   14   09   
A | 08   05   03   18   18   00   04   02   10   19   
A | 17   16   11   03   09   07   00   03   05   09   
A | 07   06   11   10   11   11   07   00   14   09   
A | 10   04   05   15   17   01   07   17   00   09   
A | 05   20   07   04   18   19   19   03   10   00
```

Comment: Stepping through your code in a debugger would show you the problem at the beginning of the second pass through your first loop. The debugger is one of the best tools you can have in your programming toolbox, and it's never too early to learn to use one.

Comment: "_Is there a way to update a separate variable inside a for-loop in C++?_" - It looks like you've figured it out. What is the real question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're resetting `k` to 65 on each iteration through your loop. You need to move the initialisation outside the loop i.e.

```
int k = 65;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        cout << char(k) << " | ";
        ++k;


       for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
        {

            cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << array_2D[i][j] << "   "; 

            // array is size [10][10]
            // array was created in a separate function

        }
        cout << endl; 

    }
```